# Oracle Running Multiplication

Tags: sql, oracle

we all know how to generate a running total column with

```
SELECT id, date, value, sum(value) 
 OVER (partition by id order by date) total 
 FROM dual 
 ORDER BY date
```

Which will give me something like

```
ID      DATE    VALUE    TOTAL
1       1/1/14  0.001    0.001
2       2/1/14  0.003    0.004
3       3/1/14  0.002    0.006
```

Now I want to generate a "running multiplication" which generated 0.001 * 0.004 * 0.006. I know that if I just want the value for the whole multiplication can be done by something like

```
SELECT exp(sum(ln(value))) from dual
```

but this one does not work with the partition in oracle. Maybe someone has an idea?

*Edit*

The desired result would be (don't mind the numbers, they are just dummies, they will not run into an overflow).

```
ID      DATE    VALUE    TOTAL
1       1/1/14  0.001    0.001
2       2/1/14  0.003    0,000004
3       3/1/14  0.002    0,000000024
```

Comment: I think they meant the LAG() analytic function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `exp(sum(ln()))` approach works as long as you add the analytics for the `sum()` part, not for the `exp()`. This would give you the product of the original values:

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, DATE '2014-01-01' AS dat, 0.001 AS value FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, DATE '2014-01-02', 0.003 FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, DATE '2014-01-03', 0.002 FROM dual
)
SELECT id, dat, value, EXP(SUM(LN(value))
  OVER (PARTITION BY null ORDER BY dat))
  AS total 
FROM t
ORDER BY dat;

        ID DAT            VALUE      TOTAL
---------- --------- ---------- ----------
         1 01-JAN-14       .001       .001 
         2 02-JAN-14       .003    .000003 
         3 03-JAN-14       .002 .000000006
```

And this would give you the product of the running total:

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, DATE '2014-01-01' AS dat, 0.001 AS value FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, DATE '2014-01-02', 0.003 FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, DATE '2014-01-03', 0.002 FROM dual
),
u AS (
  SELECT id, dat, value, SUM(value) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY null ORDER BY dat) AS total 
  FROM t
)
SELECT id, dat, value, total, EXP(SUM(LN(total))
  OVER (PARTITION BY null ORDER BY dat)) AS product
FROM u
ORDER BY dat;

        ID DAT            VALUE      TOTAL    PRODUCT
---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 01-JAN-14       .001       .001       .001 
         2 02-JAN-14       .003       .004    .000004 
         3 03-JAN-14       .002       .006 .000000024
```

Use your own table instead of the CTE obviously; and if you're trying to get the product/sum over multiple values with an ID when change it to `partition by id`. Using `null` is to make this work with your sample data.

Comment: I need similar calculation but for DIVIDE. Have you any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Unashamedly riffing off [this demonstration of a custom aggregate `product()` function](http://radino.eu/2010/11/17/product-aggregate-function/), which supports windowing, you could create your own analytic function to do the calculation for you:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE product_total_impl AS OBJECT
(
  product NUMBER,
  total NUMBER,
  product_total NUMBER,

  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(ctx IN OUT product_total_impl) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(SELF  IN OUT product_total_impl,
                                       VALUE IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(SELF IN OUT product_total_impl,
                                     ctx2 IN product_total_impl) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(SELF        IN OUT product_total_impl,
                                         returnvalue OUT NUMBER,
                                         flags       IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY product_total_impl IS
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(ctx IN OUT product_total_impl) RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    ctx := product_total_impl(1, 0, 1);
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END ODCIAggregateInitialize;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(SELF  IN OUT product_total_impl,
                                       VALUE IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    IF VALUE IS NOT NULL THEN
      SELF.product := SELF.product * VALUE;
      SELF.total := SELF.total + VALUE;
      SELF.product_total := SELF.product_total * SELF.total;
    END IF;
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END ODCIAggregateIterate;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(SELF IN OUT product_total_impl,
                                     ctx2 IN product_total_impl) RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    SELF.product := SELF.product * ctx2.product;
    SELF.total := SELF.total + ctx2.total;
    SELF.product_total := ctx2.product_total * ctx2.total;
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END ODCIAggregateMerge;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(SELF        IN OUT product_total_impl,
                                         returnvalue OUT NUMBER,
                                         flags       IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    returnvalue := SELF.product_total;
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END ODCIAggregateTerminate;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION product_total(x IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER
PARALLEL_ENABLE
AGGREGATE USING product_total_impl;
/
```

Then you can do:

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, DATE '2014-01-01' AS dat, 0.001 AS value FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, DATE '2014-01-02', 0.003 FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, DATE '2014-01-03', 0.002 FROM dual
)
SELECT id, dat, value,
  SUM(value) OVER (PARTITION BY null ORDER BY dat) AS total,
  PRODUCT_TOTAL(value) OVER (PARTITION BY null ORDER BY dat) AS product_total
FROM t
ORDER BY dat;

        ID DAT            VALUE      TOTAL PRODUCT_TOTAL
---------- --------- ---------- ---------- -------------
         1 01-JAN-14       .001       .001          .001 
         2 02-JAN-14       .003       .004       .000004 
         3 03-JAN-14       .002       .006    .000000024
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9097b/1) with the original `product` as well.

As before, use your own table instead of the CTE obviously; and if you're trying to get the product/sum over multiple values with an ID when change it to `partition by id`. Using `null` is to make this work with your sample data.