# SQL: multiply rows values per group

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table "MYTABLE" like this:

```
Id    name           gr      possibility
1     artv432        1           10
2     brtu52         1           5
3     gep2           1           2
4     cert9          2           12
```

I need to multply values in column `possibility` per group.
This is the desired output:

```
gr            possibility     
1                100             -> 10*5*2
2                 12             ->   12
```

**Update 1:**

This code does not work.

```
select exp(sum(ln(Possibility)))
```

Because `Possibility` is a decimal value and could be for example `0.56`. I used Integer value here to be easly understandable.

Comment: [is there a PRODUCT function like there is a SUM function in Oracle SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403924/is-there-a-product-function-like-there-is-a-sum-function-in-oracle-sql)

Comment: No. It only works when possibility is a number without decimals. (Integer)

Comment: Do you know how many decimals you have? Say you have 3 decimals. Can you multiply all values by, say, 1000 to convert it to integers? Then conduct your multiplication, and divide your result by 1000.

Comment: Actually there are likes 0.012 , 0.105, 1,006.

Comment: Yes I did a fast calculation of my suggestion and it does not seem to work. I suppose you may try to convert your decimals like 12*10^(-3), 105*10^(-3) etc?

Comment: `cast(exp(sum(ln(Possibility))) as decimal(20,5))` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=764a9038f26069e0169fde5fc305dec9)

Comment: Does this answer your question ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24959542/oracle-running-multiplication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a user-defined aggregation function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ProductAggregation AS OBJECT(
  value    NUMBER,

  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(
    ctx         IN OUT ProductAggregation
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(
    self        IN OUT ProductAggregation,
    value       IN     NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(
    self        IN OUT ProductAggregation,
    returnValue    OUT NUMBER,
    flags       IN     NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(
    self        IN OUT ProductAggregation,
    ctx         IN OUT ProductAggregation
  ) RETURN NUMBER
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY ProductAggregation
IS
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(
    ctx         IN OUT ProductAggregation
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    ctx := ProductAggregation(1);
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(
    self        IN OUT ProductAggregation,
    value       IN     NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    self.value := self.value * value;
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(
    self        IN OUT ProductAggregation,
    returnValue    OUT NUMBER,
    flags       IN     NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    returnValue := self.value;
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(
    self        IN OUT ProductAggregation,
    ctx         IN OUT ProductAggregation
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    self.value := self.value * ctx.value;
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;
END;
/

CREATE FUNCTION product( value NUMBER )
RETURN NUMBER
PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING ProductAggregation;
/
```

Then, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Id, name, gr, possibility) AS
SELECT 1, 'artv432', 1, 10.0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'brtu52',  1,  5.0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'gep2',    1,  2.0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'cert9',   2, 12.0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'abc',     3,  0.1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'def',     3,  0.2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'ghi',     4, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 'jki',     4,  5.0 FROM DUAL;
```

The query:

```sql
SELECT gr,
       product(possibility)
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY gr;
```

Outputs:

> | GR | PRODUCT(POSSIBILITY) |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 100 |
> | 2 | 12 |
> | 3 | .02 |
> | 4 | 5 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f462a32fac7c11a4af90d6e3e1c50049)*